# Azure deployment failing cannot find solution file?

Tags: azure, msbuild

When I deploy my repository from bitbucket, I get the following error,

```
Handling .NET Web Application deployment.  

The system cannot find the file specified. 

Failed exitCode=1, command=nuget restore "D:\home\site\repository\MySolution.sln" 

An error has occurred during web site deployment.
```

I have a .deployment file on the root of the repo with the following contents

```
[config]
command = deploy.cmd
```

I also have a deploy.cmd file on the root and will fail at the following line for some reason

```
    echo Handling .NET Web Application deployment.

    :: 1. Restore NuGet packages
    IF /I "MySolution.sln" NEQ "" (
      call :ExecuteCmd nuget restore "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\MySolution.sln"
      IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
    )
```

Why can Azure not find my solution file? Even using FTP I can see the solution file at the root of the repository...

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was because I was using encrypted password in my NuGet.config for my private nuget server, I switched to Plaintext and it worked!

Comment: How did you came to that conclusion? which steps your took to debug de deployment? I'm in a similar situation